# I can't run a while loop in Python 3.9

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.4, python-3.9

So I am a beginner in python and I have found a book about its basics. The book is based on python 3.4. The book is trying to teach me while loops. When I try to enter the code which is:

```
counter = 5

while counter > 0: print ("Counter =", counter) counter = counter - 1
```

The book says the output should be:

```
Counter = 5
Counter = 4
Counter = 3
Counter = 2
Counter = 1
```

When I try to run the code, the idle gives me a message of invalid syntax and marking the c in '**c**ounter = counter' red.

I tried fixing that by placing a comma before the word 'counter' and it worked, but when I re-ran the code, the same message popped up again but this time targeting the print command and marking its 'p' letter red.

I tried to solve that issue by placing a comma before the print command but it didn't work.

I tried writing the code with notepad++ but it also didn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: don't put it on one line

Answer (score 2):

You need to spearate multiple commands with semicolon (";"):

```
counter = 5

while counter > 0: print ("Counter =", counter); counter = counter - 1
```

However, as kabooya stated, this is not the pythonic way.
As you see, the correctly formatted source (in his answer) is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Python syntax is white-space sensitive.
Don't write things on one line.
Do it like this:

```
counter = 5

while counter > 0: 
    print ("Counter =", counter) 
    counter = counter - 1
```

Comment: hey kabooya thank you but I only did it this way because 1.the book stated it that way and 2.because it worked for me before in other situations where I placed all the code in one line.

Comment: Yeah, as Peter said, you can do it (with semicolons), but, imo that's not good practice ;)